# Not able to insert Chinese characters in MYSQL 5.5.8 and 5.6 latest one

Tags: mysql, chinese-locale

Value I am trying to inert is  - 112
If you even copy from here and insert in mysql using myslql workbench or Heidi I am getting following error

0   13:59:43    INSERT INTO test.employee VALUES ('2','112')  Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xAA\x8B\x96\xF0\xAA...' for column 'Name' at row 1

I have checked that schema , table , column has utf-8 encoding .
Also I tried with utf8mb4 , utf16 and utf32 .

Can you please help me ?

Comment: I am able to insert other chinese characters like '中文字體授權' but not what I have mentioned in question .

Comment: Also I see that refer http://www.unicode.org/~mdavis/picker/PickerData_Han_11..17-Stroke_Radicals.html in column  Less Common above characters are located which are less common .Can you please check for those in u r dbs ?

Answer (score 0):

please refer

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Problem is that these are rare han chinese character and these are four byte per char in UTF 8  than 3 bytes in UTF 8 
SO i have to change connection encoding also to utfbmb4 which was my mistake

please change my.ini as mentioned in blog

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4